# Расширение в chrome работа ссылок

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Решил сделать расширение для Chrome, получилось, но не все

```
//popup.html
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script src="myjq.js"></script>
        <script src="myjs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="https://yandex.ru/search/?text=ru.stackoverflow.com&lr=50">Моя ссылка</a
    </body>
</html>
```

Кликаю по ссылке - ест-но ничего не происходит. Подскажите, как организовать переход по ссылке ( в текущей вкладке )

p.s. да, ест-но искал, гуглил, поиск по stackoverflow дал ответ только как по клику по значку сделать переход. По ссылке внутри popup не нашел

UPD

```
//попробовал дописать после мудрых советов
<script>
function createTab() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"});
}
</script>

<a onclick="createTab();" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
```

- не сработало, видимо причина не исполнения скрипта в чем то еще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `popup` классические ссылки не работают (политика безопасности chrome-расширений).

Вам необходимо воспользоваться методом `chrome.tabs.create`.

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "http://www.google.com" });
```

А вот вариант сделать все ссылки в попапе "рабочими":

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.matches('a[href]')) {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: e.target.href});
    }
});
```

Comment: добавил файл JS в манифест, добавил там permissions нужные, добавил код в файл JS. Нажимаю на ссылку - нет перехода. Объясните подробнее, прошу

Comment: @gforce, Есть ли какие-нибудь ошибки в popup? В permissions должно быть "tabs".  Еще вариант протестировать - запустить код в консоле попапа напрямую.